# PyCharm's python interpreter error related to Anaconda3 and system

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, interpreter

I installed JetBrains Pycharm Community Edition, a python interpreter there was that of Anaconda3. When I run the project there was an error that tensorflow was not installed, however it was installed to my system itself not into anaconda's base environment. Then I deleted Anaconda from Control Panel as usual program uninstallation method and set the python interpreter of Pycharm to System Interpreter (*C:\Python354\python.exe*). When I run the project it gives the following error:

```
Error running 'Server': Cannot run program "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\python.exe" (in directory "D:\Projects\TopViewPeopleCounter"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

Although I uninstalled Anaconda, PyCharm is still looking for it as its interpreter. Then I tried to delete that Anaconda folder, but some folders inside it (**__pycache__**, **python**) are not deleted. Naturally I tried several ways of deleting it with no success:

- Uncloker did not help;
- cmd command did not help (/f del, /f rmdir );
- Disk cleanup did not help;
- Archiving the file and deleting hack did not help.

In short, the file is not deleted, when I try to access those folders pop-up window says:

```
    The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.
```

I should note that I copied the parent folder of those two folders from another place (**my previous python's** ***\Lib\site-packages***) several days ago, it was copied into *C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages*

I feel I should have issued this long before all that happened, but I honestly tried to solve it by myself.

Any further actions are aprreciated.

Comment: It will most probably not solve the problem, but I would do: File -> Invalidate caches / Restart. Just to make sure.

Comment: @Eskapp it didn't help though. I am new to PyCharm, maybe I missed something important?

Comment: @Eskapp, thanks, I could delete the folder in my `C:\Users\username\Anaconda3` but , PyCharm isn't working. In Setting>Project Interpreter I've chosen `C:\Python354\python.exe`. Is there anything important?

Comment: I would reinstall Anaconda3 and set the interpreter to the Python distribution downloaded with it. (This is located at Anaconda3\python.exe)

Comment: @Eskapp THANK YOU. It worked. I set both the interpreters of virtual environment and system environment to `C:\Python354\python.exe`